# "Exec" into specific folder

Tags: nsis

From an NSIS script (located at `C:\nsis\` for example), I execute an external program (let's say `something.bat`) with some paramerters:

```
Exec '"Z:\draft\something.bat" $param1 $param2'
```

`something.bat` is suppoed to rename the directory `C:\nsis`. My question is, how can I tell `Exec` to launch `something.bat` inside `Z:\draft\` and not `C:\nsis\`? Because, it can't rename the directory otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SetOutPath](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.9) to set the current working directory.  I think that should do what you want.

In the NSIS documentation you can also see that it uses the variable that SetOutPath sets (which is `$OUTDIR`) for `Exec` statements.

4.9.1.2 Exec

> Exec command
>   Execute the specified
>   program and continue immediately. Note
>   that the file specified must exist on
>   the target system, not the compiling
>   system. $OUTDIR is used for the
>   working directory.

Comment: Great! `SetOuPath` done the job. Next time, I'll read carefully the manual :)

Comment: @moz: No problem it's a little non intuitive, either you know it or you don't :)